# Forward request made to Azure function to another endpoint

Tags: proxy, azure-functions

I need to forward a HttpRequest made to an Azure function (through proxies.json) to a different endpoint. The request needs to be forwarded with query strings and headers intact. I need to modify the response body before sending it back to the original caller.

**Proxies.json**

```
"Transactions.BatchImport.Settlements": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/transactions/v1/getsettlementsbyid/{batchId}"
      },
      "backendUri": "http://localhost/api/storebox/settlements/{batchId}"
    },
```

**Psudocode of desired functionality**

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetStoreboxSettlements))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "storebox/settlements/{batchId}")]
    HttpRequest request, string batchId)
{
    var response = ForwardRequest(request, $"www.anotherEndpoint.com/{batchId}");
    response.Body = TransformBody(response.Body);
    return new OkObjectResult(response);
}
```

Alternative solutions are welcome.

Comment: Have you thought about using Azure API Management (in consumption tier) instead? Might be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My client has a few API's still running through Azure API Management, but are trying to move the functionality to Azure functions instead (For vendor locking / pricing reasons). I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible honestly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this is how I solved the problem:

**Proxies.json**

```json
"Transactions.BatchImport.Settlements": {
    "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/transactions/v1/getsettlementsbyid/{batchId}"
    },
    "backendUri": "http://localhost/api/v1/settlements/{batchId}"
},
```

**Function code**

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(GetStoreboxSettlementsProxy))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET",
                 Route = "v1/settlements/{batchId?}")] HttpRequest request) {
    var baseUri = _environment.Get(Constants.Api.Endpoint);
    var requestUri =
        new UriBuilder(baseUri) {
            Path = $"{request.Path}",
            Query = request.QueryString.Value,
        }
            .Uri;

    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(request.Headers["Authorization"]);
    httpRequestMessage.RequestUri = requestUri;
    HttpResponseMessage response =
        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    try {
        response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var storeBoxTransactionData =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StoreBoxTransactionData>(json);
        if (storeBoxTransactionData.TotalSize > 0) {
            // Transform storebox settlement data
            var transformedStoreBoxData =
                _processStoreBoxSettlementService.Process(
                    storeBoxTransactionData);
            response.Content = new StringContent(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transformedStoreBoxData),
                Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed to get settlements {e}");
    }

    return response;
}
```